# Too large of an integer

Tags: java, bluej

I am making a program using Java that will output the users zodiac sign. When I compile this code it highlights 0219 and says "integer number too large." I am a beginner so if this is a stupid error please be nice. Thanks

```
    System.out.println("Please enter your birthday month and day as a four digit number");
    System.out.println("(Ex: 0514 for May 14th):");
    double d = key.nextDouble();
    if (d >= 0101 && d <= 0120) {
        System.out.println("You are a Capricorn.");
    }
    else if (d >= 0121 && d <= **0219**) {
        System.out.println("You are an Aquarius.");
    }
    else if (d >= 0220 && d <= 0320) {
        System.out.println("You are a Pisces.");
    }
    else if (d >= 0321 && d <= 0420) {
        System.out.println("You are an Aries.");
    }
    else if (d >= 0421 && d <= 0521) {
        System.out.println("You are a Taurus.");
    }
    else if (d >= 0522 && d <= 0621 ) {
        System.out.println("You are a Gemini.");
    }
    else if (d >= 0622 && d <= 0723 ) {
        System.out.println("You are a Cancer.");
    }
```

Comment: Prefixing an integer literal with 0 causes it to be interpreted as a base 8 (octal) number. Get rid of the leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

Starting the number with a 0 means that it's being interpreted as octal, which makes "9" an invalid digit.

Answer (score 0):

The number input doesn't save a leading 0. If you enter 0123, and then print d, you'll see "123.0"

Just get rid of all of the leading 0s.

So you get this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Untitled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your birthday month and day as a four digit number");
    System.out.println("(Ex: 0514 for May 14th):");
Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    double d = key.nextDouble();
    if (d >= 101 && d <= 120) {
        System.out.println("You are a Capricorn.");
    }
    else if (d >= 121 && d <= 219) {
        System.out.println("You are an Aquarius.");
    }
    else if (d >= 220 && d <= 320) {
        System.out.println("You are a Pisces.");
    }
    else if (d >= 321 && d <= 420) {
        System.out.println("You are an Aries.");
    }
    else if (d >= 421 && d <= 521) {
        System.out.println("You are a Taurus.");
    }
    else if (d >= 522 && d <= 621 ) {
        System.out.println("You are a Gemini.");
    }
    else if (d >= 622 && d <= 723 ) {
        System.out.println("You are a Cancer.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, it works now. And yes I have the scanner line above, the lines of code I posted is just a piece of my class